# How to use an older version of Java FX?

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I am building a project using Java 7 with Eclipse Neon. It appears that when I try to build a JavaFX project, it will include Java 8 features. Is there any way to force an older version of JavaFX?

Comment: Are you using e(fx)clipse? If not, how are you creating the JavaFX project?

Comment: When I build the project, I go to new-> Other -> JavaFX, and build the project there. I don't think I installed it, but I don't know if Neon comes with it by default.

Comment: So then you select "JavaFX Project", and press "Next", presumably. What do you select under JRE in the next screen? And, I guess, what exactly do you mean by "it will include Java 8 features"?

Comment: I have it specified to use JAVASE-1.7. When I run it with SceneBuilder in the project, it allows me the option to build 3D objects which say (FX 8) beside it. So wouldn't this be a JavaFX 8 project?

Comment: OK, are you asking about Eclipse, or about Scene Builder?

Comment: Well, I am just trying to figure out if any of this will use Java 8 aspects? Would the JavaFX project build Java 8 items? Or would this all stay Java 7?

Comment: If you configure *Eclipse* to use Java 7, then *Eclipse* will only use Java 7 classes and language features. But Eclipse cannot control what Scene Builder does. Scene Builder is only generating the FXML anyway, so there is no real type checking.

Comment: So is there a way to make sure SceneBuilder is only doing Java 7 stuff? @James_D

Comment: Don't use controls that say "(FX 8)" next to them....

Comment: So, would that make everything Java 7 compliant? Would there be a possibility that this version of SceneBuilder does some type of Java 8 functionality?

Comment: All it's doing is generating a text (FXML) file. That file is used at runtime to instantiate classes and invoke methods using reflection. There is no Java *functionality* that SceneBuilder performs. So I guess what you mean is that you don't want to reference classes or methods that are only defined in Java 8; I don't know of any default way to do this in SceneBuilder.

Comment: Also, you do know that Java 7 is no longer publicly supported? So unless you have purchased Oracle extended support you are basically coding to an unsupported platform. Most programmers do not consider JavaFX 2.2 production quality - why do you want to use Java 7 for a GUI app?

Comment: @James_D External libraries that would rely on this project are only Java 7 compliant unfortunately

Comment: I find it hard to imagine how an external library would rely on a UI project.

Answer (score 0):

SceneBuilder showing FX8 stuff has nothing to do with your actual application. Like what some people have suggested, don't use things labeled with FX8.

Eventually, what SceneBuilder does is simply generating what you designed (with its visual designer) into FXML. If the FXML includes classes (Controls) that aren't part of Java 7 API, the application will throw exception when you launch.

If it contains Controls present in Java 7 but FX8 provides additional properties (or attributes in FXML), and you have specified those properties in SceneBuilder, most likely those FXML attributes will be ignored. I haven't tested it, so there is always a possibility that it might throw exceptions as well; it all depends on how `FXMLLoader` is designed.

In Summary, take note of these:

1. Avoid (I mean totally don't) using Controls labeled with FX8.
2. Make sure your project's build path uses Java 7 library.
3. Try loading the FXML that the SceneBuilder generates - if it doesn't throw exceptions, it means that the loaded graph of nodes are Java 7 compliant.